# Strange allow/deny question on Huawei 5.1 phone when showing notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, huawei-mobile-services

So it turns out that Huawei phones with 5.1 can't display `MediaStyle` notifications so while fixing that, I made a very simple notification test and I get a strange question asking `Allow App Name to push messages to the notification panel`.

I don't use push in any way, in fact the screenshot below is for an app that all it does is show a sample notification, nothing else.

How can I make it not show that?

This is the code:

```
 Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setContentTitle("Track title")
                .setContentText("Artist - Album")
                .setOngoing(true)

                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_add_black_24dp, "fwd", pi)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp, "fwd", pi)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_archive_black_24dp, "fwd", pi)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black_24dp, "fwd", pi)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_aspect_ratio_black_24dp, "fwd", pi)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_fast_forward_black_24dp, "fwd", pi)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.vectors_525058875))
                .setAutoCancel(false)


                .build();
        notificationManager.notify(300, notification);
```

This is the screenshot.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I tried taking out all the actions, that didn't help. Took out title and context, that didn't help. Took out large icon, auto cancel, ongoing, etc, didn't help.

Please note that I am not using Push in any way and this doesn't seem to be related to that. Also I a using the support compat libraries to make my notification but on this example I didn't just to make sure that wasn't the issue.

Comment: it's Huawei customized Android OS feature. Long story short, you can't disable it.

Comment: But how come some other notifications don't show it?

Comment: Because you tested a lot and Huawei thinks your notification might annoy the end user(yourself, in this case).  I saw it a lot when I test my app.

Comment: Oh interesting, so this only happens during testing? Oh well, their phone doesn't even support `MediaStyle` so it is all messed up as it is.

Comment: yes, it quit sucks.

Comment: Did you want to put that on an answer so I can make it as correct since you mentioned this first?

Comment: Thanks, I appreciated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Huawei customized Android OS feature. Long story short, you can't disable it.

I saw it a lot when I test my app. Huawei OS thinks your notification might annoy the end user(yourself, in this case) because it happened a lot.

You don't have to concern it

Answer (score 3):

Huawei's version of the Android OS has a custom feature that tries to spot apps doing annoying numbers of notifications.

Don't focus on the word "push". It doesn't mean "push notifications" in the technical sense of coming from the internet. It just is a verb, they could have said "allow app to create notifications" or "allow app to cause notifications" it's the same meaning.

Anyway, this is an OS feature, there is nothing you can do to avoid it except make sure you aren't spammy with your notifications. Unfortunately during development and testing you will often be triggering *a lot* of notifications, and the OS will detect your app is spammy. Don't worry about it. As long as your app works well for normal users it shouldn't happen.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the info.

Answer (score 0):

Your use deprecated constructor. Your must specify channel. Like this:

```
Notification.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,"MyPerfectApplication")
```

Otherwise you use unknown chanel, possible you try to push in system channel.

Comment: This phone has android 5.1 which doesn't have channels, also I am using the `NotificationCompat` on my actual code, I just used the normal one on this sample to make sure the compat library wasn't the issue.

Answer (score 0):

it's indeed a custom check of [EMUI](https://consumer.huawei.com/en/emui/), which enables the user to decide whether or not to have these custom notifications being pushed into the default notification channel, *before* a single one of these notifications had ever been displayed, when the first push is being attempted. it generally controls the notification settings of your app on Huawei devices, from within that notification panel. system & vendor applications are permitted to push notifications by default and therefore it won't ever ask the user for a double confirmation there. this has nothing to do with excessive notifications, because it is a precondition to even have these notifications pushed, no matter the amount.