# MediaStyle : RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-notifications, huawei-mobile-services

I'm trying to create a notification media controller in my app using the code below  which is working fine on all devices expect **Huawei P8 Lite** with **Android 5.0** , I get this error log from Firebase Test Lab :

> android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from
>   package maa.app_app: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for:
>   StatusBarNotification(pkg=maa.app_app
>   user=UserHandle{0} id=555 tag=null score=10
>   key=0|maa.app_app|555|null|10108: Notification(pri=1
>   contentView=maa.app_app/0x109007f vibrate=null
>   sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x62 color=0xffbfbfbf category=transport
>   actions=2 vis=PUBLIC)) FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process:
>   maa.app_app, PID: 18793
>   android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from
>   package maa.app_app: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for:
>   StatusBarNotification(pkg=maa.app_app
>   user=UserHandle{0} id=555 tag=null score=10
>   key=0|maa.app_app|555|null|10108: Notification(pri=1
>   contentView=maa.app_app/0x109007f vibrate=null
>   sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x62 color=0xffbfbfbf category=transport
>   actions=2 vis=PUBLIC))    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1534)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5538)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

here's my code :

```
void startNotify(Context context, String playbackStatus, String title) {
    String titlesonge;
    String artist;
    try {
        titlesonge = StringUtils.substringBefore(title, " - ");
        artist = StringUtils.substringAfter(title, " - ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        titlesonge = title.substring(0, title.indexOf(" - "));
        artist = title.substring(title.lastIndexOf(" - ") - 1);
    }
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_pause_white;
    Intent playbackAction = new Intent(service, RadioService.class);
    playbackAction.setAction(RadioService.ACTION_PAUSE);
    PendingIntent action = PendingIntent.getService(service, 1, playbackAction, 0);
    if (playbackStatus.equals(PlaybackStatus.PAUSED)) {
        icon = R.drawable.ic_play_white;
        playbackAction.setAction(RadioService.ACTION_PLAY);
        action = PendingIntent.getService(service, 2, playbackAction, 0);

    }
    Intent stopIntent = new Intent(service, RadioService.class);
    stopIntent.setAction(RadioService.ACTION_STOP);
    PendingIntent stopAction = PendingIntent.getService(service, 3, stopIntent, 0);

    Intent intent = new Intent(service, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(service, 0, intent, 0);
    notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
    String PRIMARY_CHANNEL = "PRIMARY_CHANNEL_ID";
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) service.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String PRIMARY_CHANNEL_NAME = "PRIMARY";
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(PRIMARY_CHANNEL, PRIMARY_CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
        channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
        if (manager != null) {
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(service, PRIMARY_CHANNEL)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setContentTitle(titlesonge)
            .setContentText(artist)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.largeicon))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.smallwidth)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorneeded))
            .addAction(icon, "pause", action)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_stop_white, "stop", stopAction)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setStyle(new android.support.v4.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                    .setMediaSession(service.getMediaSession().getSessionToken())
                    .setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1)
                    .setShowCancelButton(true)
                    .setCancelButtonIntent(stopAction));
    service.startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
}
```

can anyone help me to get resolved this issue

Answer (score 4):

For some reason, Huawei devices with Android 5.0 crashes when using `.setStyle()` method so you have two possibilities :

1 - detect device Manufacture if is Huawei or not, and have an Android 5.0 or below or not

```
public boolean isLolliPopHuawei() {
    return (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1 ||
            android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) && Build.MANUFACTURER.equalsIgnoreCase("HUAWEI");
}
```

2 - Use `PlayerNotificationManager` instead

```
void exoPlayerNotification(Context context, SimpleExoPlayer exoPlayer, String title) {
    String titlesonge;
    String artist;
    try {
        titlesonge = StringUtils.substringBefore(title, " - ");
        artist = StringUtils.substringAfter(title, " - ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        titlesonge = title.substring(0, title.indexOf(" - "));
        artist = title.substring(title.lastIndexOf(" - ") - 1);
    }
    String finalArtist = artist;
    String finalTitlesonge = titlesonge;
    mPlayerNotificationManager = PlayerNotificationManager.createWithNotificationChannel(
            context,
            "PRIMARY_CHANNEL_ID",
            R.string.plaza,
            NOTIFICATION_ID,
            new PlayerNotificationManager.MediaDescriptionAdapter() {
                @Override
                public String getCurrentContentTitle(Player player) {
                    return finalArtist;
                }

                @Nullable
                @Override
                public PendingIntent createCurrentContentIntent(Player player) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(service, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    return PendingIntent.getActivity(service, 0, intent,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                }

                @Override
                public String getCurrentContentText(Player player) {
                    return finalTitlesonge;
                }

                @Nullable
                @Override
                public Bitmap getCurrentLargeIcon(Player player, PlayerNotificationManager.BitmapCallback callback) {
                    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(service.getResources(), R.drawable.largeicon);
                }

                @Nullable
                @Override
                public String getCurrentSubText(Player player) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
    );
    mPlayerNotificationManager.setUseNavigationActions(false);
    mPlayerNotificationManager.setFastForwardIncrementMs(0);
    mPlayerNotificationManager.setRewindIncrementMs(0);
    mPlayerNotificationManager.setColorized(true);
    mPlayerNotificationManager.setColor(0xFFEEEEEE);
    mPlayerNotificationManager.setUseChronometer(true);
    mPlayerNotificationManager.setOngoing(true);
    mPlayerNotificationManager.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);
    mPlayerNotificationManager.setUsePlayPauseActions(true);
    mPlayerNotificationManager.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.smallwidth);
    mPlayerNotificationManager.setNotificationListener(new PlayerNotificationManager.NotificationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onNotificationStarted(int notificationId, Notification notification) {
            service.startForeground(notificationId, notification);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNotificationCancelled(int notificationId) {
            service.stopSelf();
            cancelNotify();
        }
    });
    mPlayerNotificationManager.setPlayer(exoPlayer);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that `PlayerNotificationManager` would fix the issue; it also unconditionally passes a `MediaStyle` to `setStyle()`. https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/41b3fc110178e9a5c969a0102c5b074189065273/library/ui/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/PlayerNotificationManager.java#L1050

Answer (score 1):

Since some Huawei devices don't support MediaStyle you need to build notification without styling. I experienced this issue on this models Huawei P8 Lite and Huawei Y3II. So, check if device is huawei and SDK versions as mentioned and create a simple notification as below. This question helped me to find solution [Strange allow/deny question on Huawei 5.1 phone when showing notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54874512/strange-allow-deny-question-on-huawei-5-1-phone-when-showing-notification)
. Anyway, I hope helps someone

```
    boolean isLollipopHuawei = (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1 ||
            android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) && Build.MANUFACTURER.equalsIgnoreCase("HUAWEI");


    if (isLollipopHuawei) {

        builder
                .setContentTitle(description.getTitle())
                .setContentText(contentText)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setContentIntent(createContentIntent())
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                        R.drawable.mobi_plc))

                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_previous_outline_notification,
                        this.service.getString(R.string.next_station),
                        MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(
                                this.service,
                                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS))
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_next_outline_notification,
                        this.service.getString(R.string.next_station),
                        MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(
                                this.service,
                                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT))

                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat)

                .setAutoCancel(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the root cause was not able to setStyle, it was only giving this exception in Huawei P8 Lite, not on other devices.

So, what i had to do was check if current device is android version 5.0 and its manufacturer is Huawei and remove the setStyle property. please check below code

```
boolean isLollipopHuawei = (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1 ||
            android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) && Build.MANUFACTURER.equalsIgnoreCase("HUAWEI");


if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1 || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

            if (isLollipopHuawei) {

                return builder
                        .addAction(generateAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_previous, "Previous", Constants.ACTION_PREVIOUS))
                        .addAction(action)
                        .addAction(generateAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_next, "Next", Constants.ACTION_NEXT))
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.vpicon_grayscale)
                        .setContentTitle(getSongDataHelper().getTitle())
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setContentText(getSongDataHelper().getAlbum())
                        .setLargeIcon(getSongDataHelper().getAlbumArt())
                        //.setColor(color)
                      /*  .setStyle(new androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                                .setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1, 2)
                                .setMediaSession(mMediaSession.getSessionToken()))*/
                        .build();
            } else {
                return builder
                        .addAction(generateAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_previous, "Previous", Constants.ACTION_PREVIOUS))
                        .addAction(action)
                        .addAction(generateAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_next, "Next", Constants.ACTION_NEXT))
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.vpicon_grayscale)
                        .setContentTitle(getSongDataHelper().getTitle())
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setContentText(getSongDataHelper().getAlbum())
                        .setLargeIcon(getSongDataHelper().getAlbumArt())
                        //.setColor(color)
                        .setStyle(new androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                                .setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1, 2)
                                .setMediaSession(mMediaSession.getSessionToken()))
                        .build();
            }
        }
```